# Can a PartialView be changed dynamically based on which View it is rendered in?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a PartialView which populates a variable list of items with each item containing inputs specific to one of the items. This list is displayed on each of the Create, Edit, and Details Views. The problem with this is that while the Create and Edit Views need to be able to modify all of the inputs, I want the inputs on the Details page to be Read-only. I know how to do this via:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Foo[i].Bar, new { htmlAttributes = new { @readonly="readonly" } })
```

Is it possible to dynamically set the readonly attribute from within a PartialView, based on which View is currently rendered so that if the Details View is rendered, all of the inputs are set to readonly?

I realize that one solution is fairly simple: Duplicate the code from the PartialView in the Details View and set the inputs to readonly there. I would, however, prefer to keep all of that code in the same place and avoid such duplication if possible =)

Comment: You could simply use the ViewBag to indicate that they should be rendered read-only. The controller would set the ViewBag's property accordingly.

Comment: If its a readonly details view, why are you rendering controls? And what about select's, checkboxs and radio buttons? Use display templates not editor templates.

Comment: I agree with Stephen. I think you should have a separate read only details view.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: The purpose of using EditorFor was to maintain a consistent look and feel across all of the views. Sure I could have used DisplayFor to render these fields, but then I would have had to create extra css to make the fields look right in order to keep the users happy. Setting the controls to readonly seemed like the best solution. The purpose of this question was just to try to keep the razor code for my list of child items contained within the PartialView... It seems like duplicating the code and keeping the Details view completely separate is the way I'll end up going with it, though.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you could create a helper method:

```
public class Extensions
{
    public static string EditorWithReadOnlyFor(
        this HtmlHelper helper,
        Expression<Func<TModel,TProperty>> expression,
        bool readonly)
    {
        // Use bool to manipulate attributes then
        return helper.EditorFor(expression, /* add attributes */ )
    }
}
```

You should be able to use it like this:

```
@Html.EditorWithReadOnlyFor(x => x.Foo[i].Bar, true)
```

Comment: This still suffers from the problem of not being able to set it dynamically. Using this, I would still have to use this custom helper exclusively on the Details page, in which case why not use a regular helper and set the readonly property there? I suppose I could set the value in the ViewBag to set the readonly property, but it still seems unnecessary to create custom code for that.

That said, thanks for sharing this. I am admittedly new to MVC and Razor and hadn't really looked into custom helpers yet. This prompted me to do so =)

Answer (score 0):

based my understanding of your problem . you seems need to set the readonly attribute dynamically .

you can add IsReadOnly in your ViewModal and you View :

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Foo[i].Bar, new { htmlAttributes = new { @readonly=@Model.IsReadOnly }
```